# Button not responding when clicked

Tags: java, android, xml

I am new to `Android Programming` and I wanted to make a simple app where the user would enter there name and after they click the button, it would say `Hello (name of person)`. Also the button will change to `thanks for clicking me` after it is clicked. I have looked through the code but I am having a hard time finding the error. I have the code down below. I will also add the xml under the code.

`code`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText yourName;
private TextView outputName;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    yourName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.inputText);
    outputName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.outputText);
}

public void printHello (View view){

    Button button =(Button) view;
    ((Button)view).setText("Thanks for Clicking Me!");

    yourName =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.inputText);
    outputName =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.outputText);

    outputName.setText("Hello, "+ yourName.getText());
    outputName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }
}
```

Here is the xml also

```
   <Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="328dp"
    android:text="Talk to Me"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.078" />

   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/Label1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="31dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:text="                      Please Enter Your Name"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/outputText"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="88dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/inputText"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

   <EditText
    android:id="@+id/inputText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="72dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="Name"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Label1" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have an `android:onClick="printHello"` inside of the button XML to link the button to the function inside of the Java class. Then any time the button is clicked, it calls printHello and does what you need to.

Comment: Thanks! I went to my button and added it from there.